# How to find/kill a specific python program

Tags: linux, bash, ps, grep

There are two different python programs running in this VM

one is a background job who monitors a folder and then 'does stuff' (with several workers)

```
10835 ?        Sl     0:03 python main.py
10844 ?        Sl    34:02 python main.py
10845 ?        S     33:43 python main.py
```

the second one is started via script

```
20056 pts/1    S+     0:00 /bin/bash ./exp.sh
20069 pts/1    S+     0:00 /bin/bash ./exp.sh
20087 pts/1    S+     0:10 python /home/path/second.py
```

i have tried numerous things to find a way to kill only the main program (i want to build a cron watchdog), but non succeded

first one i want to find only the hanging 'python main.py' process (accompanied by [defunct]), but i cant even find just this process alone.

the upper ones are from ps -ax (so they both are running currently)
pgrep 'python' returns all PIDs, also from second.py which i dont want: (not usefull, so is pkill therefore)

```
pgrep 'python'
10835
10844
10845
20087
```

pgrep 'python main.py' always returns empty, so does pgrep 'main.py;

the only thing which works

```
ps ax | grep 'python main.py'
```

but this one also returns its own PID, grepping 'ps' isn't a prefered solution afair. when main.py hangs, it shows "python main.py [defunct]". a

```
ps ax | grep 'python main.py [defunct]'
```

is useless as test as it always returns true. pgrep for anything more than 'python' also returns always false. i am a bit clueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your daemon python script you should create PID file:

```
def writePidFile():
  pid = str(os.getpid())
  f = open('/tmp/my_pid', 'w')
  f.write(pid)
  f.close()
```

Now killing this process is simple:

```
kill `cat /tmp/my_pid`
```

Or you can just use `grep` and filter its own process:

```
ps ax | grep 'python main.py [defunct]' | grep -v grep
```

Comment: ty, this should work, need to check in detail how to do with all the workers. the question is still open how can i find out that the script is hanging (ps -ax --> python main.py [defunct]). i'd prefer a bash solution here over main.py writing each 5min a status file.

Comment: ty, with this line i don't even need to add the line to the python script. i can just kill the PIDs when true.

Comment: The final solution has two problems; `[` does not match a literal `[` but instead introduces a regex character class -- so `[defunct]` matches a single character which is c or d or e or f or n or t or u and so is equivalent to the regex `[cdefntu]`. Secondly, the `grep -v grep` will be unnecessary once you replace the regex with one which doesn't match itself.  Commonly `grep 'foo' | grep -v grep` can be refactored to `grep '[f]oo'` but once you fix the regex, no further refactoring will be necessary.  So `ps ax | grep 'python main\.py \[defunct\]'` (note also proper quoting of the period).

Answer (score 6):

This works for me. Found it on the `pgrep` [bro pages](http://bropages.org/pgrep).

#### Find the pids of processes with 'test.py' as an argument, like 'python test.py'

```
pgrep -f test.py
```

And I use it to check if a python process is running:

```
searcher="backend/webapi.py"

if pgrep -f "$searcher" > /dev/null
then
    echo "$(date +%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S) $searcher is alive. Doing nothing."
else
    echo "No $searcher. Kickstarting..."
    pushd $HOME/there/;
    ./run_backend
    popd;
    echo "Pgrepping $searcher:"
    pgrep "$searcher" # out to loggers
fi
```

Comment: And a killer would be `kill $(pgrep -f test.py)`

Comment: This is dangerous. It's a good way to kill your editor too.

`# pgrep -a -f test.py`
`29728 vim test.py`
`29773 python test.py`

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a pretty safe way to do find the proper python process PID for a specific file only. The idea is to find all the python processes, then all "test.py" processes and intersect the results to find the correct PID.

I use the subprocess module in a python script (you can interpolate for .sh script):

```
import subprocess as subp
#Get a list of all processes with a certain name
def get_pid(name):
    return list(map(int,subp.check_output(["pidof", "-c", name]).split()))
#Get a list of all pids for python3 processes
python_pids = get_pid('python3')
#Get a list of all pids for processes with "main.py" argument
main_py_pids = list(map(int,subp.check_output(["pgrep", "-f", "main.py"]).split()))
python_main_py_pid = set(python_pids).intersection(main_py_pids)
print(python_pids)
print(main_py_pids)
print(python_main_py_pid)
```

Result with 3 running python processes (including the one from this script) and one "sudo nano main.py" process:

```
Python pids: [3032, 2329, 1698]
main.py pids: [1698, 3031]
Interesection: {1698}
```